# How do I evolve Yen pins?

Tags: the-world-ends-with-you

In the game, *The World Ends With You*, the info for Yen pins say that they can evolve. However, every Yen pin I've come across has been a mastered pin, which is locked out of Pin evolution.

How do I evolve a Yen pin? Is there a way to find unmastered Yen pins?

[image: 1 Yen pin info page]

Comment: I remember getting exactly one unmastered Yen pin in all the time I played TWEWY, but don't happen to remember when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmastered Yen pins can be purchased from shops as Quest items once you have high enough relationship with the shopkeeper.

| Pin | Price | Area | Store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Yen | 2x Rare Metal | Shibukyu Stationside | Sunshine Stationside |
| 5 Yen | 2x Rare Metal | Cadoi City | Mus Rattus III |
| 10 Yen | 4x Rare Metal | 104 Building | Mus Rattus I |
| 50 Yen | 4x Tektite | Shibukyu Stationside | KuraKura |
| 1,000 Yen | 6x Tektite | AMX | AMX |
| 5,000 Yen | 12x Rare Metal | Spain Hill | Mexican Dog |

The 1 Yen pin can evolve into a 5 Yen or 10 Yen pin depending on the PP it is leveled up with. Other pins will evolve from Battle PP.

| Original Pin Name | PP Type (DS) | PP Type (Remix) | Evolved Pin Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Yen | Shutdown | - | 5 Yen |
| 1 Yen | Mingle | Battle | 10 Yen |
| 5 Yen | Battle | - | 50 Yen |
| 10 Yen | Battle | - | 100 Yen |
| 50 Yen | Battle | - | 500 Yen |
| 100 Yen | Battle | - | 1000 Yen |
| 500 Yen | Battle | - | 5000 Yen |
| 1000 Yen | Battle | - | 1 Yen |
| 5000 Yen | Battle | - | 10000 Yen |

Table data from TWEWY Wiki: [Shop List](https://twewy.fandom.com/wiki/Shop_List) & [Pin Evolution Table](https://twewy.fandom.com/wiki/Pin_Evolution_Table)